# Jenkins Docker installation on demand

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am configuring a jenkins pipeline with one stage that pull a docker maven image to compile a java application. When it starts it gives me a docker not found error.

I  would like to know how could be installed Docker automatically. I've configured the option to install automatically in the panel admin but does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, because I am also interested, and also for others, kindly please can you provide more details, like you are using [Docker commons plugin?](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Commons+Plugin) 
check the description under question marks, eg. on installation path: `A directory containing bin/docker. Or leave blank to use docker from $PATH.` 
Not sure, what 'install automatically' should do in this case `If you check this option, you'll then be asked to configure a series of "installer"s for this tool, where each installer defines how Jenkins will try to install this tool.`

Comment: I am using Docker plugin but no sure if it is related to the installation of Docker...I've configured the installer to download from Docker website. When I configure a stage to use a docker image (the maven image one for instance) does not install anything